# Render blocking issue in google page insight

Tags: javascript

I found render blocking issue for css and js file plz need help to solve without plugin.

I am using following code but it defer all js file. My webiste will break. How can i slove this issue

```
function add_defer_to_cf7( $url )
{

    if(strpos( $url, 'https://testing.vcclcloud.com/wp-content/plugins/elementpress/addons/widgets/epress-effects/assets/js/effects.js?ver=2.2.4') > 0)){ 
       return "$url' defer='defer";
    }
    
}
add_filter( 'clean_url', 'add_defer_to_cf7', 11, 1 );
```